# ¿Cómo puedo condicionar un botón para que no ejecute si tiene valores diferentes?

Tags: java, android

lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguiente:
que los artículos que pertenecen a la misma lista se puedan pedir, y si existe un artículo que pertenece a otra lista, envíe una notificación y no permita continuar.

agrego el código de lo que pretendo hacer.

```
btnPedir = findViewById(R.id.btn_pedir);
            btnPedir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        for (int i=0; i<mUploads.size(); i++) {

                            String lists = mUploads.get(i).getmListBD();

                            for (Upload current : mUploads) {

                                if (lists.equals(current.getmListBD())) {

                                    subirPedido();
                                    Toast.makeText(CarShop.this, "Solicitud Exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(CarShop.this, "Las Listas no Coinciden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Que propiedad determina pertenecer a una lista u otra?

Comment: Hola Elenasys es un String, varia en tres listas "Outle", "Offer" y "myList". le agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, asigné valores booleanos a cada lista y la condicioné muchas gracias a todos. espero mi participación sea la correcta, realmente soy nuevo en Stack Overflow